# How can I pass method as an function argument?

Tags: function, c++11, methods, arguments

I have the code below, but it will not compile, telling me:
"error: invalid use of non-static member function".
Is there a way to pass such method as an function argument without making it static?

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual int method() = 0;
}

class Derived1: public Base{
public:
    int method(){ return num; }
private:
    int num;
}

class Derived2: public Base{
public:
    int method(){ return dif_num; }
private:
    int dif_num;
}

template <class T>
int func( T obj, int(*f)() ){
    std::cout<<obj->f()<<std::endl;
}




int main(){
    Derived1* obj = new Derived1();
    func( obj, obj->method/*????*/ )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use a function pointer. Use a `std::function` instead.
2. Use a lambda expression in the call to `func`. It will be converted to a `std::function` by the compiler.

```
template <class T>
int func( T obj, std::function<int()>f ){
    std::cout<<obj->f()<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Derived1* obj = new Derived1();
    func( obj, [obj]() -> int {return obj->method();} )
}
```